# yii: serve a file when logged in

Tags: yii

I have pdf files in a htaccess-protected directory that I want to show to some users in Yii application.

How is best to solve that? I understand it should be done inside Yii, not with a separate script as it needs to check if a valid user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

[Access control filters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter)

Answer (score 0):

You would do your appropriate security checking (user is in group, or has permission or whatever) and then you would use [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) or something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20pdf%20download&submit=search).

Do you have code already that isn't working? Or did you just need help with what approach to take?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

I got some idea from this link:

http://harrybailey.com/2011/07/yii-rewrite-files-or-images-for-download-or-display/

In short: made a new actionfunction into controller and in that function sending headers and readfile.